# How to reshape an array in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array: `array([[59], [72], [117], ..., [15530], [13091], [983]], dtype=object)`, witch shape is `(39104L,)`. How to reshape it into array, like `array([59, 72, 117, ..., 15530, 13091, 983], dtype=float32`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your original array is a 1d array of lists:

```
array([[59], [72], [117], ..., [15530], [13091], [983]], dtype=object)
# shape (39104L,)
```

Normally something like that would be a 2d array in integers

```
In [796]: x=np.array([[59], [72], [117], [15530], [13091], [983]])
In [797]: x
Out[797]: 
array([[   59],
       [   72],
       [  117],
       [15530],
       [13091],
       [  983]])
In [798]: x.shape
Out[798]: (6, 1)
```

But if one or more of those lists had a different number of elements you'd get the object array:

```
In [799]: x=np.array([[59], [72], [117], [15530,34], [13091], [983]])
In [800]: x
Out[800]: array([[59], [72], [117], [15530, 34], [13091], [983]], dtype=object)
In [801]: x.shape
Out[801]: (6,)
```

That accounts for errors like:

```
In [804]: np.asarray(x, dtype=float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

but

```
In [805]: x.tolist()
Out[805]: [[59], [72], [117], [15530, 34], [13091], [983]]
```

Try something like this to see if any of the elements of your array are longer than 1:

```
In [806]: max([len(i) for i in x])
Out[806]: 2
```

You might also need to display the type of one or more elements to confirm my suspicion:

```
In [807]: type(x[0])
Out[807]: list
```

Also, how was this array constructed?

Answer (score 0):

If the shape is (n_items,) then it's already a one-dimensional vector. If you want to get a "plain" Python list from this, use [`numpy.ndarray.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

For reshaping in general, there's the [`numpy.reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method.

Comment: It returns an Error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Comment: If your numpy array is called `my_array`, what's the output of `type(my_array)`?

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it, your array should have a shape of `(39104L,1)`, not `(39104L,)`. That is, the array has a redundant dimension. You can remove this by using `np.squeeze`.

For general reshaping, you can of course use `np.reshape`, which can also be used instead of `np.squeeze` in your case.

Another aspect of your question is that you change the `dtype` of the array. For that, you can use

```
a = np.asarray(a, dtype='float32')
```

where `a` is your array.

Comment: I've made it, but it output an Error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: You should edit your question and post a complete code example. You have some error which cannot be seen right now because details are missing.